# MySQL timestamp math behaves differently after using unix_timestamp()

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out what MySQL is doing during the math operation of timestamps.

Picture of resulting problem:

[image]

You'll see on the left I have two timestamps, start and end, and I need to find the duration from start to end so I just do this:

end - start

I was getting some really weird results. You can see for a duration of only 3 hours I was getting result back that indicated 2 to 3 times that amount.

When I convert to UTC first, the math works out fine.

Can anyone explain what SQL is doing with the timestamps on the left?  I've always been under the impression that all timestamps are UTC under the hood, which is why things like min, max, less than, etc work without converting.

Thanks!

Code:

```
select  
    min(timestamp) start, 
    max(timestamp) end, 
    max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) start_to_end, 
    unix_timestamp(min(timestamp)) startUTC, 
    unix_timestamp(max(timestamp)) endUTC,
    unix_timestamp(max(timestamp)) - unix_timestamp(min(timestamp)) start_to_end_UTC
from post_snapshots group by permalink;
```

Comment: Could it be [this?:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) `MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. `

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a `DATETIME` vs. `TIMESTAMP` or a time zone problem.

MySQL handles datetimes as operands to a subtraction (or other mathematical operation) by converting each value to a number, but it's not the number of seconds, its just the datetime digits crunched together. Take an example from your data:

`2013-02-19 16:49:21` becomes `20130219164921`

`2013-02-19 19:07:31` becomes `20130219190731`

The difference between those two numbers is... 25810, which is the value you're seeing as the result of your subtraction operation. That's not a result in seconds, as you noted. It really doesn't mean much useful at all.

In contrast, [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) (or pre-converting to Unix timestamps as you did) actually performs the difference using time-appropriate math if you're looking for the difference to be significant for much beyond sorting:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2013-02-19 16:49:21', '2013-02-19 19:07:31')
>>> 8290
```

Answer (score 1):

These examples have nothing to do with timezone conversions -- when you subtract one date directly from the other, MySQL generates a integer from all existing date parts and then makes the math operations. For example, this query:

```
select now()+1;
```

returns (it was '2013-02-26 14:38:31' + 1):

```
+----------------+
| now()+1        |
+----------------+
| 20130226143832 |
+----------------+
```

So the difference between "2013-02-19 16:49:21" and "2013-02-19 19:07:31" turns out to be:

```
20130219190731 - 20130219164921 = 25810
```

The correct way for getting this subtraction is to either convert the dates to timestamps (like you did) or to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_date, end_date)`, which would return 8290.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is you cannot substract dates/datetimes in mysql. For all math operations, the mysql timestamp data type behaves like datetime data type.
You could use instead

```
  select  
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,min(timestamp),max(timestamp))
  from post_snapshots group by permalink;
```